# Class in python

Tags: python, class

I have created a class called `Functions` which contains many functions
I define this function:

```
def distance(self,seq1,seq2,seq3)
```

In another file I want to call the function of this class.

I have defined three DNA sequences:

```
a=Functions()
a.distance(seq1,seq2,seq3)
```

When I try to call `Functions()`, I get the following error:

```
name 'Functions' is not defined
```

Comment: You need to import it. `from myfile import Functions`

Comment: First, make sure the files are in the same directory. Second, in the 2nd file, you have to import the first one.

Comment: why people vote this down?

Comment: @Elisha: I don't know. There are ways you could make it _better_ (including a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), post the full traceback instead of just part of the error, etc.), but it doesn't seem downvote-worthy to me. Some people seem to think that questions that are too "elementary" are automatically bad. Personally, I think there are good, decent, and bad questions at every level of knowledge, and yours is a decent elementary question.

Comment: @abarnert, first, this is not my question. second, I also feel like sometimes people mixed between elementary questions and bad questions, that what made me comment about it. it is better to say in a comment where can be improved on the question then immediately vote it down.

Comment: @Elisha: Sorry for mixing you up with the OP. Anyway, you could bring this up on meta and see what people think over there. Maybe you could get a consensus, and then you could link to the meta question every time you see people downvoting a question just for being too elementary.

Comment: I want to ask a question but I can't , I receive this message:Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, if the file is named  `distance.py` for example, you just:

```
import distance
a = distance.Functions()
```

Or if you feel lazy:

```
from distance import Functions
a = Functions()
```

Or if you feel very lazy:

```
from distance import *
a = Functions()
```